# unit test to cover thread run inside a inner class

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have a java class defined as below:

```
package com.sample.ut;
public class Outer {
    private class innerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          synchronized(this) {
                final PendingResult result = goAsyn();
                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doAsync(intent); //TODO
                        result.finish(); //TODO
                    }
                };
                thread.start();
            }
        }
    }
    private void doAsync(Intent intent) {
            //do work here
    }
}
```

How can I write UT code to cover two lines inside the inner class thread runner? I need do it since code coverage tool report that two line not being covered.

Comment: and what did you try until now?